# How to use method "decimalSeparator" from NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app I try to check if user enters right decimal separator depending on local settings (if user makes mistake, that pice of data doesn't enter CoreData database) :

```
- (void)save {
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

I get user input:

```
NSString *firstForDistance = _forDistanceTextField.text;
```

try to extract decimal separator from string:

```
NSString *separator = [firstForDistance decimalSeparator];
```

than check if separator fits users local settings or he made typo. In case of typo or mistake i replace it with decimal separator from his local settings:

```
if (separator != [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]) {
    firstForDistance = [firstForDistance stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:[locale objectForKey: NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]];
}
```

Rest of code:

```
self.user.forDistance = [numberFormatter numberFromString:firstForDistance];

[self.delegate usersMakeViewController:self addUser:self.user];
}
```

That would be nice and easy, but extracting doesn't work:

```
NSString *separator = [firstForDistance decimalSeparator];
```

method "decimalSeparator" is instance method from NSNumberFormatter and i get fault from Xcode.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can check like below string have decimalSeparator or not**

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    if ([textField.text rangeOfString:numberFormatter.decimalSeparator].location != NSNotFound) 
        NSLog(@"YES,  Give number has decimalSeparator");
    else
        NSLog(@"NO, dont have decimalSeparator");
```

Comment: Thank you @Narayana, that is also handy and i'll consider it but i would like to replace separator if user makes typo (period for coma or opposite), depending of his local settings.

Comment: @user1868438 can you explain more

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *firstForDistance = _forDistanceTextField.text;

firstForDistance = [firstForDistance stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:[locale objectForKey: NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]];
firstForDistance = [firstForDistance stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:[locale objectForKey: NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]];

self.user.forDistance = [numberFormatter numberFromString:firstForDistance];
[self.delegate usersMakeViewController:self addUser:self.user];
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: 1,000.75 ==> 1.000.75 or 1,000,75? Nope (BUZZZZ!)